# RunAs creates a Job. How can I manage my nested processes in such a Job?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp, win32-process

I have an application that spawns some sub-processes.
I need to guarrantee that if the super-process dies, all sub-processes die with it.
I managed to do this creating a new Job Object with `CreateJobObject` and `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` and assigning the super-process to it.
Here is some simplified code in Delphi (no error-checking etc.):

```
procedure TFoo.InitJob;
var
  jLimit: TJobObjectExtendedLimitInformation;
  bInJob: LongBool;
begin
  // Create Job Object. All sub-processes will be automatically included 
  FJobObject := CreateJobObject(nil, PChar(Format('Global\%d', [GetCurrentProcessID])));
  jLimit.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags := JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
  SetInformationJobObject(FJobObject, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, @jLimit, SizeOf(TJobObjectExtendedLimitInformation));
  // Add the cutrrent process in the new Job only if it is not already in a job
  IsProcessInJob(GetCurrentProcess, 0, bInJob);
  if (not bInJob) then
    AssignProcessToJobObject(FJobObject, GetCurrentProcess);
end;
```

Now I have to run the application from a batch file through `runas`.
Unfortunately, it seems that `runas` starts a Job itself, and puts my process inside it.
Then `runas` ends, but this `unnamed Job` remains.
I investigated with ProcessExplorer and seems that this `unnamed Job` hasn't any limit.
But if I kill the parent process, sub-processes survive.
I'm running under Windows XP SP2 or Windows 7. No Windows8, so No Nested jobs.

Can I (and how) do `SetInformationJobObject` on that job?
How else can I make any sub-process die with its parent in this scenario?

Edit: I guess that `runas` didn't set `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` flag because if I `CreateProcess` with `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` I get an "Access denied" error.

Thank you

Comment: If your application already starts in a job it did not create, it most probably is not allowed to change anything about this job. The solution is to create a new job, start your child processes with the creation flag `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` and then move your processes to the job you created for them. Your master application stays where it is. It won't live in the same job the child processes do but as long as you've set the `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE`, you're fine.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful: do you happen to know whether runas sets `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` ?  Also note that you need to use the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag to avoid a race condition; resume each child process only after you've added it to the job.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sorry, I've never used the `runas` command. As far as I recall, a process that was spawned from explorer.exe always starts up in a job that was already created for it. Could you please elaborate on the race condition? Why would you start the child processes in suspended mode, then add them to the job and then resume them? I always dare to just create a process and then call `AssignProcessToJobObject` on the process handle.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful: I can assume that `runas` didn't set  `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK`, as Harry suggested, because if I `CreateProcess` with `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` i get an "Access denied" error. I'm just editing my question. Thank you for your suggestion, anyway.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful: the race condition is that the child process might launch a child process of its own before `AssignProcessToJobObject` completes, and that process would then be left out of the job.  In practice I think this is unlikely to happen because it takes quite a long time for a new process to start in Windows, but strictly speaking it isn't impossible.

Comment: It should be possible to escape the job using a system service, but I'm not sure whether there is a more straightforward way.

Comment: Have you tried to use ShellExecute(Ex) with "runas"?